# Alternative solution for concurrent.sessions when someone is not using pro version for R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

When concurrent session is available only for pro version then without pro version can we show some session busy message to the users?

I've one shiny app deployed in Linux system. But that's not a pro version. But I need some solution for the user who are hitting the web app parallelly so that they don't get any errors.

Comment: You can spin another shiny app and navigate the users to the app that wasnt last and try to go round robin with it. You can use `iframe` to create the page for access where you simply navigate between `app1` and `app2`

Comment: 1. Any Article link for that how to do that
2. If I've understood your approach then this will solve 2 simultaneous users not ore than that. But I want to show a message page wen it is busy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look into `promises` https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html